# c# - How to change the generic specific class

Tags: c#, list, generics, generic-list

I have a generic method. I want check if the list is `Users` type. If yes, change the list to:

```
List<Users>
```

Is this possible?

```
public void setList<T>(List<T> list)
{
    List<Users> listUsers;
    if (list is Users)
    {
        //listUsers = list;
    }

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Comment: The list can't ever be `User`, since it's a `List` of something. I think you meant if an element is of type `User`. Unless you really want to turn your `User` (which is a list) to a List of users (which is a list of lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast to from `List<T>` to `List<Users>`, because `List<T>` does not support covariance with respect to the type parameter (for more on this topic, see for example [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)).  However, you can always cast to an interface.  So if `IList<Users>` is acceptable for you to use (and it should be I think), then you can work with this:

```
public void setList<T>(List<T> list)
{
    IList<Users> listUsers;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Users))
    {
        listUsers = (IList<Users>)list;
    }

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type at run time. But you could set the type to `object` or a base class or interface common to both types. That should allow you to do what you want (although you haven't been very specific about what you want).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can have an non-generic overload along with your generic one:

```
public void setList(List<Users> list)
{
    // processing specific for List<Users>

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

compiler will figure out on its own which overload to call, no need for run-time checks.